# Sclera detection

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

I'm writing an algorithm for sclera detection on grayscale images and I found a formula that I cannot explain how it works. Here is the paper segment I'm trying to use:
[image: thresholding]

Here it says that I should use the HSL information of the image and calculate 3 thresholds for the 3 components which I later use for thresholding. The problem is that I cannot make any sense of the notation arg{t|min| ...} as they are not explained at all in the paper.

I deduced how the sum works and that I should have a constant at the end of the computation of the sum, but what does this previosuly mentioned operator do with the constant gathered from the sum I cannot find anywhere.

I tried to search for the meaning of the arg notation, but this wikipedia page doesn't seem to give me any answers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)

Here they say that the result of the operation is the angle of the complex number, however I don't have any complex numbers, therefore if I consider a real number as complex my angle will always be 0.

Can anyone explain what should this operation do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

arg in this case means the argument of the function that gives the minimum value:

e.g .

```
m=arg{min f(x)}
```

is the x value for which the function f achieves its minimum value.

It's a standard notation in image classification etc. If you look at this you will see it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_a_posteriori_estimation

Comment: Thank you! You solved the part with the argument, but I still don't understand what do they want to say about the sum of the normalized histogram. As far as I remember from image processing classes normalization of the histogram means that you add up all the values of the histogram and divide each value by the sum in order to have the sum of the histogram equal with one. In this case the dispersion of the histogram does not matter, because the sum will always be one, so the whole thing will reduce to a constant of 1 - T.

Comment: you are absolutely right in this one; normalizing means find the min and max and then newv=(oldv-min)/(max-min); if your histogram is 3 5 3 the first would give 3/11 5/11 3/11 the second 0 1 0; you can try both and see the effect - but it's the common meaning in the literature it's  the probability thats why they probably use px